# Java Swing 2D Array of Panels not repainting with Swing Timers

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, repaint

I'm new to Java Swing and I have been working on creating a Connect 4 Game which supports multiplayers through a server with a gameRoom. I have been working on this particular problem for almost 2 days and while solving it have fixed problems such as stopped the use of Thread.sleep and thoroughly tested that the Game object is passed on correctly to and from the server.

The way I architected is that each move is submitted through the model's make move command. In order to refresh the GUI, the server sends back a new Game object to the model and marks the controller attribute 'setRepaint' as true. Then, a timer periodically checks if this attribute is true and calls the repaintGrid() method.

After many hours of trying to get this to work, I cannot get the game panels to repaint.

Some points which might help:

- If I quit the application and restart it with a Game object that already has moves on it, the panels are painted. The problem is with the repaint method.
- The model is static and gets it Game attribute updated every time the                 Connect4App.model.getGameFromServer() is called. Not sure if this would cause problems but if I print the panels that are being repainted as red/blue, I can verify that the game object is updated successfully by the server on each iteration.
- The frame hierarchy is the following: The guiMain is a container for the gamePanel which has a gridlayout, each filled in by a GridPanel panel. The Grid panels are essentially the slots for the tokens of the Connect4 Game and those are the ones that I try to update in the repaintGrid method

  ```
  import java.awt.GridLayout;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.Timer;

  public class GameController {

  MouseAdapter me;
  private JPanel gamePanel;
  private boolean setRepaint = false;

  /**
   * Constructor for the Game Controller. Takes in a view and a model
   * 
   * @param view
   * @param model
   */
  public GameController() {
      setupGridPanels();
      setupMouseAdapter();
      Connect4App.frame.setContentPane(Connect4App.guiMain);
      Connect4App.frame.setTitle("Game View");
      goIntoTimer();

  }

  /**
   * Repaint Boolean used by timer. Set to true by external program
   */
  public void setRepaint() {
      this.setRepaint = true;
  }

  /**
   * Swing Timer which checks if it needs to repaint every 8 seconds and if
   * so, calls repaintGrid
   */
  private void goIntoTimer() {
      Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              Connect4App.model.getGameFromServer();

              if (setRepaint == true) {
                  repaintGrid();
                  setRepaint = false;
              }

          }
      });
      timer.setRepeats(true);
      timer.setDelay(8000);
      timer.start();

  }

  /**
   * Sets up the Initial Game Panels in the Connect4App.guiMain panel
   */
  private void setupGridPanels() {
      this.gamePanel = new JPanel();
      this.gamePanel.removeAll();

      // setting up the layout for, the game board.
      this.gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, Connect4App.model.getGame().getGrid()[0].length));

      int numberOfRows = Connect4App.model.getGame().getGrid().length;
      int numberOfColumns = Connect4App.model.getGame().getGrid()[0].length;

      for (int r = 0; r < numberOfRows; r++) {
          for (int c = 0; c < numberOfColumns; c++) {
              Connect4App.guiMain.setCircleArc(r, c, new GridPanel(r, c));
              this.gamePanel.add(Connect4App.guiMain.getCircleArcs()[r][c]);
          }
      }
      Connect4App.guiMain.add(this.gamePanel);
  }

  /**
   * Sets up the mouse pressed event handleres for every panel
   */
  private void setupMouseAdapter() {
      MouseAdapter mc = new MouseAdapter() {

          @Override
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mc) {

              GridPanel cell = (GridPanel) mc.getSource();

              // this is the column that should go in the MakeMove message
              int column = cell.getColumn();
              int row = cell.getRow();

              if (Connect4App.model.getGame().getGrid()[row][column].getState() == 0) {
                  System.out.println("attempting to make move");
                  Connect4App.model.makeMove(column);
              }
          }
      };

      for (int r = 0; r < Connect4App.model.getGame().getGrid().length; r++) {
          for (int c = 0; c < Connect4App.model.getGame().getGrid()[0].length; c++) {
              Connect4App.guiMain.getCircleArcs()[r][c].addMouseListener(mc);
          }
      }
  }

  void repaintGrid() {

      // --> This is supposed to be working
      System.out.println("repainting");

      for (int r = 0; r < Connect4App.model.getGame().getGrid().length; r++) {
          for (int c = 0; c < Connect4App.model.getGame().getGrid()[0].length; c++) {
              Connect4App.guiMain.getCircleArcs()[r][c].validate();
              Connect4App.guiMain.getCircleArcs()[r][c].repaint();
          }
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Any help would be appreciated :-D

Comment: There appears to be done use of static which could be an issue. There could also be an issue between the threads reading/writing the state variable

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MadProgrammer . I tested and it seems like the state is being updated properly at the point that the paintComponent method is called by repaint :-s

Comment: Can you print out a debug message inside the loops? (Also, I could be wrong but are you sure `validate()` is correct? How about `revalidate()` or `invalidate()`? It's a while since I've done something like this.)

Comment: This code does not show where the GridPanel content is changed (the ones returned from getCircleArcs()). Could you post that part as well?

Comment: As a sidenote, it is much easier to help you if you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. It turns out the I was having a problem with sending the same object back and fourth through objectoutputstreams (the game state) without reseting the streams and so this was causing the client not to receive updates all of the times. The repainting code above was working. Closing the thread, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the I was having a problem with sending the same object back and fourth through objectoutputstreams (the game state) without reseting the streams and so this was causing the client not to receive updates all of the times. The repainting code above was working. Closing the thread, thanks again.